# How to access NVIDIA Quadro K4000 from my remote desktop Windows 10?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu, remote-desktop

I have been trying to access my NVIDIA Quadro K4000 GPU from my remote desktop Windows 10. I need to use it for TensorFlow object detection version 2.9 or greater. For TensorFlow 2.9 or higher I have installed CUDA and cuDNN 11.2 and visual studio 2019 according to the build configuration. It runs perfectly on my local PC and shows the local GPU on my laptop after running this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
```

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

But this line of code doesnot show any GPU device when I connect to my remote desktop with NVIDIA Quadro K4000 GPU.

This line of code returns null value:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

I have tried everything from editing path variable to editing with 'gpedit.msc' from Run command. I cannot use my GPU remotely. I am stuck for long time.

Please help me.

[Tried editing all these. but in vain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4wsP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I was unaware about the compute capability of my GPU and the version of CUDA and cuDNN I was using on the system. It took me two days for this but now I have access to my Tensorflow-GPU version 2.0.0.